# C++ SDL Angular motion point to point by a click

Tags: c++, floating-point, sdl, rounding, physics

Im trying to move a object from A point to B point by a click. Each frame the object will move a litlle to the B point. My code works but its doesnt do exactly what I want.

This is what I mean:
I have two code, this is the first one...

```
class tank {

public:

    void setMoveTank(tank &_tank, int x, int y) {
        _tank.tanke.moving = true;
        _tank.tanke.x2 = x;
        _tank.tanke.y2 = y;

        int vx      = _tank.tanke.x2 - _tank.tanke.x;
        int vy      = _tank.tanke.y2 - _tank.tanke.y;
        if(vx==0) vx+=1; if(vy==0) vy+=1; //float core dumperra arreglateko
        double alfa = atan2(vy,vx) * 180 / M_PI;

        _tank.tanke.vx = 2*cos(alfa*( M_PI / 180));
        _tank.tanke.vy = 2*sin(alfa*( M_PI / 180));
    }

    void renderTank(render _render, tank &_tank) {
        if(_tank.tanke.moving) {
            _tank.tanke.x += _tank.tanke.vx;
            _tank.tanke.y += _tank.tanke.vy;
        }

        SDL_Rect dst = {(int)(_tank.tanke.x),(int)(_tank.tanke.y),_tank.tanke.spr.w,_tank.tanke.spr.h};
        SDL_RenderCopy(_render.ren, _tank.tanke.img, &_tank.tanke.spr, &dst);
    }
```

};

...and do something like this

[I calculate angle once and I move object every frame, but it never arrive to destination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuuTq.jpg)

This is my second code...

```
class tank {

public:

    void setMoveTank(tank &_tank, int x, int y) {
        _tank.tanke.moving = true;
        _tank.tanke.x2 = x;
        _tank.tanke.y2 = y;
    }

    void renderTank(render _render, tank &_tank) {
        if(_tank.tanke.moving) {
            int vx      = _tank.tanke.x2 - _tank.tanke.x;
            int vy      = _tank.tanke.y2 - _tank.tanke.y;
            if(vx==0) vx+=1; if(vy==0) vy+=1; //float core dumperra arreglateko
            double alfa = atan2(vy,vx) * 180 / M_PI;

            _tank.tanke.vx = 2*cos(alfa*( M_PI / 180));
            _tank.tanke.vy = 2*sin(alfa*( M_PI / 180));

            _tank.tanke.x += _tank.tanke.vx;
            _tank.tanke.y += _tank.tanke.vy;
        }

        SDL_Rect dst = {(int)(_tank.tanke.x),(int)(_tank.tanke.y),_tank.tanke.spr.w,_tank.tanke.spr.h};
        SDL_RenderCopy(_render.ren, _tank.tanke.img, &_tank.tanke.spr, &dst);
    }
```

};

... and do something like this

[this code do what I want but I must recalculate de angle each frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXP6B.jpg)

The problem is that, in the second code, the object doesnt draw a rect line and in the first code, the object never arrive to the B point.

Im sure that the problem is in the ROUND, but how can I fix it? What would the best way to make this?

```
    int main() {

            if(event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
                switch(event.button.button) {
                    case SDL_BUTTON_LEFT:   _tank.setMoveTank(_tank, event.button.x, event.button.y);   break;
                }
            }

        }
        SDL_RenderClear(_render.ren);
        _tank.renderTank(_render, _tank);
        SDL_RenderPresent(_render.ren);
    }
}
```

hiii

EDIT: this is the fixed code

```
void renderTank(render _render, tank &_tank) {
    if(_tank.tanke.moving) {
        double vx      = _tank.tanke.x2 - _tank.tanke.x;
        double vy      = _tank.tanke.y2 - _tank.tanke.y;
        if(vx==0) vx+=1; if(vy==0) vy+=1; //float core dumperra arreglateko
        double alfa = atan2(vy,vx) * 180 / M_PI;

        _tank.tanke.vx = 2*cos(alfa*( M_PI / 180));
        _tank.tanke.vy = 2*sin(alfa*( M_PI / 180));

        _tank.tanke.x += _tank.tanke.vx;
        _tank.tanke.y += _tank.tanke.vy;
    }

    SDL_Rect dst = {(int)(_tank.tanke.x),(int)(_tank.tanke.y),_tank.tanke.spr.w,_tank.tanke.spr.h};
    SDL_RenderCopy(_render.ren, _tank.tanke.img, &_tank.tanke.spr, &dst);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are storing the velocity as an integer. This causes a lot of precision to be lost, and this is why it goes at a slightly different angle in the first example. In the second example you try to adjust the velocity every frame, which causes it to flip between 2 directions which are both off because of a lack of precision.

Store both the position and velocity as floating point values, and only cast them to integers when you need to draw the tank on the screen.